# "On tomorrow" vs. "by tomorrow"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct?

> - I will transfer the amount **on** tomorrow.
> - I will transfer the amount **by** tomorrow.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could say one of two things:

> I will transfer the amount tomorrow.
>
> I will transfer the amount by tomorrow.

The first indicates that the transfer will occur tomorrow exactly. The second indicates that the transfer might occur before tomorrow, but will not occur later than tomorrow.

This is just incorrect:

> I will transfer the amount on tomorrow.

You never use the preposition *on* to govern adverbs such as *today* or *tomorrow*.

Comment: But note this is just a peculiarity of words such as *yesterday* and *tomorrow*. You can say you will transfer the money *Tuesday,* *on Tuesday,* *by Tuesday,* and they will all be correct. Here *on Tuesday* means the same thing as *Tuesday*.

Comment: "Tuesday" without a preposition is rather rare in the UK, and sounds distinctly American to me. "August" is less uncommon, but not as common as "in August". So in the UK there is a clear split between named periods ("Tuesday", "August", "2011") which generally require a preposition, and special words ("today", "tonight", "tomorrow", "yesterday", "last month") which do not permit one.

Comment: In Australia we also use prepositions with the nouns which are the names of days of the week or months of the year. But words like "tomorrow" function as adverbs as well as nouns which is why they don't take prepositions when used as in the example question.

Comment: I think we can make this answer better by including all of the limited number of pertinent adverbs. So rather than the current conclusion, _You never use the preposition on to govern adverbs such as today or tomorrow_, we could have _You never use the preposition on to govern the following adverbs: today, tomorrow, and yesterday, last week, last night or last [name of any day of the week] or next week or nest [name of any day of the week.] Not sure that's the most elegant wording for the next and last bit. Are there other adverbs that belong on the list? To edit or not to edit?

Answer (score 8):

To add to JSBangs's answer, the use of "tomorrow" may be masking your real question, which seems to be when to use "on" versus "by".  Consider instead:

I will transfer the money on Friday.
I will transfer the money by Friday.

The first says that you will take this action specifically on Friday; the second says that by Friday you will have done it, maybe on Friday or maybe on Thursday or whenever.

Answer (score 5):

I never heard "on tomorrow" before I moved to North Carolina from Pennsylvania. Here, the same person who says "on tomorrow" is equally likely to pronounce "asked" as if it were spelled "axed."

As regards "by tomorrow" I have observed the following distinction:

- If I say "Please transfer your money to me by tomorrow", I mean
  before the end of business today.
- If I say "I will transfer my money to you by tomorrow", I mean I will
  transfer the money sometime before midnight tomorrow night. Or before
  sometime in the morning day after tomorrow.

This is both humorous and true. And it applies equally to the way promises are made to me.

The meaning of "by tomorrow" is in part a function of who will be doing it and partly a reflection of who is the beneficiary. Auto mechanic says "I'll have it done by Friday." If I actually show up to get my car at 7:30 Friday morning, I would not be at all surprised to hear him say "I said 'by Friday,' not 'by first thing Friday.'"

Answer (score 3):

`by tomorrow` makes sense, but technically it means that when tomorrow arrives the thing in question will already be done. In other words, `by` there means `before`.

On tomorrow I have never heard used, and would consider incorrect English. However, I have seen `on the morrow` used. It is kind of an archaic way of saying that something will be done in the morning.

If you just want to say that something will be done the next day (not before, but on that day), you'd simply say `tomorrow`.